# I keep getting the same error when using 'IPointerEnterHandler' in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am relatively new to C# and have come across an error that is as follows:

> Assets\CardDrop.cs(6,54): error CS0535: 'CardDrop' does not implement interface member 'IPointerEnterHandler.OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData)'

and

> Assets\CardDrop.cs(6,76): error CS0535: 'CardDrop' does not implement interface member 'IPointerExitHandler.OnPointerExit(PointerEventData)'

The code I have is followed:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class CardDrop : MonoBehaviour, IDropHandler, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    public void OnEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("OnEnter");
    }

    public void OnExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("OnExit");
    }

    public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log(eventData.pointerDrag.name + "Was dropped on " + gameObject.name);

        Draggable d = eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<Draggable>();
        if(d != null)
        {
            d.parentToReturnTo = this.transform;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your class claims to implement the IPointerEnterHandler and IPointerExitHandler interfaces, but it doesn't implement the members of those interfaces.

Comment: and even tells you whats wrong

Answer (score 0):

Naming matters when implementing interfaces!

As the erros tell you it should be

```
public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("OnEnter");
}

public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("OnExit");
}
```

See [`IPointerEnterHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerEnterHandler.html) and [`IPointerExitHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerExitHandler.html).

Answer (score 0):

You are inheriting from the unimplemented interfaces `IPointerEnterHandler` and `IPointerExitHandler`.

As the error is telling you (emphasis mine)

> Assets\CardDrop.cs(6,76): error CS0535: 'CardDrop' **does not implement interface member** 'IPointerExitHandler.OnPointerExit(PointerEventData)'

You need to add the following methods:

```cs
public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    throw new System.NotImplementedException();
}

public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    throw new System.NotImplementedException();
}
```

if you are using an IDE like visual studio you can automate this by hovering over the interface that is missing its implementation, and pressing `ctrl + .`

More information on how interfaces work, and why they *need* to be implemented can be found on the [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/) (emphasis mine)

> An interface is typically like an abstract base class with only abstract members. **Any class or struct that implements the interface must implement** all its members. Optionally, an interface may define default implementations for some or all of its members.